# Can someone explain a double type assertion I don't understand from the Encyclopedia sample?

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript Encyclopedia sample code in data.js uses a double type assertion that doesn't seem to accomplish anything:

```
export interface Group {
  key: string;
  title: string;   
}

interface Groups {
  [idx: string]: Group;
}

var groupsHash = **<Groups>(<any>**{ 
  recent: { key: 'recent', title: 'Recent' },
  favorites: { key: 'favorites', title: 'Favorites' },
  today: { key: 'today', title: 'Today' },
  nearby: { key: 'xxnearby', title: 'Nearby' }
});
```

In fact, the use of these type assertions seems to make using the groupsHash variable harder, as it adds all kinds of things to the Intellisense instead of what would happen if those type assertions weren't there. Can someone explain them to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `<any>` cast isn't needed and does not affect anything as the only reference to that object is via the `groupHash` variable which the compiler infers to be of type `Groups` on account of the `<Groups>` cast. I am not sure why the person who wrote the code wrote it this way as casting directly to Groups seems to work just fine in my attempts -- perhaps the code was written for an earlier version of the compiler that needed it?

With that said I'm not sure what you mean when you say "it adds all kinds of things to the Intellisense", since the only type information the compiler should have on groupHash is that it references some object that implements the Groups interface. When I was playing around with this code, having the intermediate cast to "any" made no difference at all. VS 2012 Express gave me no autocompletion for groupHash until I used the bracket property access notation on it with a string key, at which point it listed Group's "key" and "title" properties as expected.

EDIT: Just realized you probably meant no type casts at all, at which point the type of "groupHash" would be the full inferred signature of that object literal (so all of the 4 properties in the definition would be listed by intellisense).

The reason this wasn't done was because the idea is that "groupHash" is meant to be used as a hashtable -- so you can dynamically add and remove properties from it at runtime. While you could still use it that way without casting it to the Groups interface, the communication of how you intend the object to be used isn't as clear. I.e., new programmer looks at the code, sees it has those 4 properties on it, assumes this static type will be upheld through the program's lifespan, then gets a surprise at runtime when all of a sudden the object looks completely different as things get added and removed from it.